# presto sql - aggregate product of two columns with numbers stored as strings

Tags: sql, amazon-s3, presto, amazon-athena

I am trying to  aggregate product of two columns where numbers are stored as  strings.  I tried to convert the columns into numeric values then multiply and aggregate, but I am getting errors.

**The query is built in Amazon/Athena environment  (Presto)**

**UPDATE** 
**After further investigation I found that in the dataset there are some records with negative prices and those most likely are causing the problem here**

There is the example:

**"dataset"."table1"**

```
product   price    quantity
==========================
(string) (string)  (string)
 A        5         1 
 A       -1        1
...
```

**SQL Code**

```
 SELECT 
    product
    , sum ( coalesce(cast(nullif(price,'') as DECIMAL(28, 2)),0) * coalesce(cast(nullif(quantity,'') as DECIMAL(28, 2)),0))
 FROM "dataset"."table1" 
 WHERE
    price is not NULL and price not like '0' 
    and quantity is not NULL  and  quantity not like '0' 
    GROUP BY
    product
```

> ERROR: INVALID_CAST_ARGUMENT: Cannot cast VARCHAR ' SUBS' to DECIMAL(28, 2)

The below query works fine though

```
SELECT 
product
,coalesce(cast(nullif(price,'') as DECIMAL(28, 2)),0)
,coalesce(cast(nullif(quantity,'') as DECIMAL(28, 2)),0)
from "dataset"."table1" 
WHERE
price is not NULL and price not like '0' 
and quantity is not NULL  and  quantity not like '0'
```

**How to work around the conversions and aggregate the product of the two columns?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I worked that around using the WHEN CASE  in the SELECT

```
sum( CAST( (CASE WHEN price like '-%' Then  concat('-', substr(price, 2, Length(price)) )  ElSE price  END ) as DECIMAL(28,2) ) * CAST( quantity as DECIMAL(28,2) ) )
```

Answer (score 2):

I would consider wrapping your CAST in TRY (see https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/conditional.html).
The error you have shown above indicates that your data is not clean.
There is no way the string ' SUBS' can be turned into a number.